# ClassNotFoundException in NativeScript using .extend()

Tags: javascript, java, android, nativescript

I am trying to extend GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks(), but keep getting an error

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.sampleGroceries/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException:  Calling js method onCreate failed
>
> Error calling module function
>
> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient_ConnectionCallbacks
>       java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>       java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:324)
>       java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:285)
>       com.tns.DexFactory.generateDex(DexFactory.java:262)
>       com.tns.DexFactory.resolveClass(DexFactory.java:120)
>       com.tns.ClassResolver.resolveClass(ClassResolver.java:45)

`

My corresponding code is

```
var GoogleApiClient = com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
var myConnectionCallbacks = GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.extend({
onConnected: function(connectionHint){
    var MessageListener = MessageListener.extend({
            onFound: function(message){
                Log.d("MESSAGE", "Found message :) ");
            },
            onLost: function(message){
                Log.d("MESSAGE", "Lost message :( ");
            }


    });
    var mMessageListener = new MessageListener();

},
onConnectionSuspended: function(){}

});
    var MessagesOptionsBuilder = new com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessagesOptions.Builder().setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE).build();
    var test = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API, MessagesOptionsBuilder);
    test.addConnectionCallbacks(new myConnectionCallbacks(this));
```

Maybe I misunderstood the Docs?
https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface

Edit: Why is there an underscore in the error log after GoogleApiClient?

Any suggestions what I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your are trying to extend an interface which is wrong . More info -> https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/generator/extend-class-interface#interfaces

```
var MessagesOptionsBuilder = new com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessagesOptions.Builder().setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE).build();
var test = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API, MessagesOptionsBuilder);
test.addConnectionCallbacks(new com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks({
    onConnected: function (connectionHint) {
        var MessageListener = MessageListener.extend({
            onFound: function (message) {
                console.log(Found message :) ");
            },
            onLost: function (message) {
                console.log("Lost message :( ");
            }


        });
        var mMessageListener = new MessageListener();

    },
    onConnectionSuspended: function () { }

}));
```

and just incase the MessageListener is an interface the just remove the .extend

```
var MessagesOptionsBuilder = new com.google.android.gms.nearby.messages.MessagesOptions.Builder().setPermissions(NearbyPermissions.BLE).build();
var test = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).addApi(Nearby.MESSAGES_API, MessagesOptionsBuilder);
test.addConnectionCallbacks(new com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks({
    onConnected: function (connectionHint) {
        new MessageListener({
            onFound: function (message) {
                console.log(Found message :) ");
            },
            onLost: function (message) {
                console.log("Lost message :( ");
            }


        });

    },
    onConnectionSuspended: function () { }

}));
```